# I have imported Selenium and I thought it was installed with Python, I cannot find where this is going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver #This is where the error 
from getpass import getpass

usr = input("enter your username or email id: ")
pwd = getpass("Enter your password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')

username_box = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
username_box.send_keys(usr)

password_box = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
password_box.send_keys(pwd)

login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_2')
login_btn.submit()
```

When I run the code it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jarre\OneDrive\Documents\FB automation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"
```

And I'm not sure why when Selenium was installed with Python?

Comment: How did you install Selenium? pip install selenium is a good way to install it.

Comment: I thought it was installed with python, as when i searched it that was what it said

Comment: Please link to the source that told you that when you install python you automatically get selenium as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Selenium is not installed.

A better approach would be to use **pip** to install the **selenium package**.

> **Python 3.6** has pip available in the standard library. Using pip, you can install selenium like this:

```
pip install selenium
```

If you are on windows machine :

1. Start a command prompt using the **cmd.exe** program and run the **pip** command as given below to install selenium.

> C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe install selenium

Now you can run your test scripts using Python.

For example, if you have created a Selenium based script and saved it inside **C:\my_selenium_script.py**, you can run it like this:

```
C:\Python35\python.exe C:\my_selenium_script.py
```

For more you can refer this [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

Comment: "Python 3.6 has pip available in the standard library.". Technically irrelevant since you're running a command line script.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : Well, that's the official docs says : (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

Comment: @MadPhysicist : I believe pip is available in the standard library , using that we are installing selenium through command line.

Comment: So it does. Anything that's not your own words should be quoted with a leading `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is not natively included with the python installation.

`pip install selenium` should solve your issue.